# InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext isn't an Application context?

Tags: android, testing, dagger-hilt

When using EarlyEntryPoints.get() with InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext, Hilt throws an error of "Could not find an Application in the given context" when trying to use it.

Why isn't InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext an Application context?

This is from an androidTest's setup() code where I'm trying to grab some build configuration info out of the app under test by using an entrypoint to get access to it.
Without Hilt (i.e. from a test that is not annotated with @HiltAndroidTest and without using the @CustomTestApplication from the testrunner), this works fine.